# Rolling file in Tinylog overwrites a log file on every app start

Tags: java, kotlin, tinylog

I'm using the tinylog in version 2.6.2 in Kotlin.
This is my tinylog.properties file:

```
writer2 = rolling file
writer2.level = info
writer2.file = #{tinylog.directory}/log_{date:yyyy-MM-dd}.{dynamic:Unknown}.txt
writer2.backups = 30
writer2.format = {date:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {level}: {message}
writer2.policies = daily, dynamic
writer2.charset = UTF-8
```

But tinylog creates overwrites the log file every time I start my application.
Do you know why? And what can I do to force tinylog to append logs to the existsing log file until the day or my dynamic part change?

Comment: Seems like according to flowing [manual](https://tinylog.org/v2/configuration/)  you can use `writer.latest   = latest.log            # optional link to the latest log file
` In any case, I suppose it's better idea to switch into [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) with [logback](https://logback.qos.ch/) instead of using an exotic logger.

Comment: Your configuration is absolutely correct. `writer.latest` won't fix it. Actually, this is a bug in tinylog itself. I'm the main developer of tinylog and going to fix the bug tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with overwriting existing log files at startup when using the `{dynamic}` placeholder has been fixed in [tinylog 2.7.0-M3](https://tinylog.org/v2/news/#2024-01-09-third-milestone-of-tinylog-2.7-is-out).

You can download the new version here: https://tinylog.org/v2/download-preview/